# ThemeData: 'colorSchemeSeed == null || primaryColor == null': is not true

Tags: flutter

```
// Our light/Primary Theme
ThemeData themeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: appBarTheme,
    primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
    colorSchemeSeed: kAccentLightColor,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
      secondary: kSecondaryLightColor,
      // on light theme surface = Colors.white by default
    ),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kBodyTextColorLight),
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
        const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: kAccentIconLightColor),
    primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kPrimaryIconLightColor),
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme().copyWith(
      bodySmall: const TextStyle(color: kBodyTextColorDark),
      bodyMedium: const TextStyle(color: kBodyTextColorDark),
      bodyLarge: const TextStyle(color: kBodyTextColorDark),
      headlineMedium: const TextStyle(color: kTitleTextDarkColor, fontSize: 32),
      headlineLarge: const TextStyle(color: kTitleTextDarkColor, fontSize: 80),
    ),
  );
}
```

I am trying to customize themData but whenever i am calling it from another class this is showing some error.I tried a lot but didn't work. Indicating that colorSchemeSeed == null || primaryColor == null. But why this is showing i can't understand. This is showing this type of error:

The relevant error-causing widget was:
The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty):

```
#2      new ThemeData (package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart:462:12)
#3      themeData (package:analogclock/theme.dart:8:10)
#4      MyApp.build (package:analogclock/main.dart:17:14)
#5      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5156:49)
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5086:15)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#8      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5068:5)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5062:5)
...     Normal element mounting (27 frames)
#36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3708:18)
#38     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1240:16)
#39     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1209:5)
#40     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1156:18)
#41     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2720:19)
#42     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1155:13)
#43     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:988:7)
#44     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:968:7)
#48     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because only `primaryColor` or `colorSchemeSeed` can be set simulatanously.

```
// Our light/Primary Theme
ThemeData themeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: appBarTheme,
    // if you set primaryColor, colorSchemeSeed must be unset, otherwise unset your primaryColor
    primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
    // colorSchemeSeed: kAccentLightColor,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
      secondary: kSecondaryLightColor,
      // on light theme surface = Colors.white by default
    ),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kBodyTextColorLight),
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
        const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: kAccentIconLightColor),
    primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kPrimaryIconLightColor),
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme().copyWith(
      bodySmall: const TextStyle(color: kBodyTextColorDark),
      bodyMedium: const TextStyle(color: kBodyTextColorDark),
      bodyLarge: const TextStyle(color: kBodyTextColorDark),
      headlineMedium: const TextStyle(color: kTitleTextDarkColor, fontSize: 32),
      headlineLarge: const TextStyle(color: kTitleTextDarkColor, fontSize: 80),
    ),
  );
}
```